# Unmerge a branch

Tags: node.js, git, visual-studio-code

I merged a branch in dev using vscode: git merge branch1

I want to unmerge this branch1 from dev and have the original code that was in dev before merging the branch.

I tried pulling the dev branch's code again: git pull origin dev. But I got notification that branch is already-upto-date.

So can I unmerge the branch. Also, I have not committed the merged branch into dev. So original code of dev is still there in git.

Comment: Did you push to the remote after making the erroneous unwanted merge?

Comment: `git reset --hard HEAD^` will probably do the trick. It means “reset this branch to the state it was one commit ago (the ^ can be put multiple times to go back multiple steps). If you want to then push it to a remote you’ll have to possibly force it. But be careful with reset, especially with hard since you can lose things (or at least make it difficult to get them back)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen no I have not pushed to the remote.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Actually I have not pushed anything into dev. I have just merged the code locally. So code in original code in dev in git is still there.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Actually, it would be better to hard reset to the exact hash of the prior commit.  Reason being, a merge commit has 2 parents, so I'm not sure that `HEAD^` would always be correct here.